# Translating from Python to Robot, how to import a library

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to write some API tests that require a specialized wrapper. The Library that I am using takes the API request, examines it, and using a private key, generates a signature header based on the size of the request, timestamp and other things before sending the request to the server.

Here is the Proof of concept code written in python3

```
import requests
from auth_client.requests_auth import Auth

APP_UUID = "redacted"
private_key = open("private_key", "r").read()

signature = Auth(APP_UUID, private_key)

uuid="redacted"
url = "https://www.example.com/v1/rest/{}/index".format(uuid)
headers = {'AdditionalHeader': 'redacted'}

result = requests.get(url, auth=signature, headers=headers)

print(result.text)
```

And so far I have gotten this far trying to write it in robot framework:

```
Library       requests
Library       auth_client.requests_auth

*** Variables ***
    ${additionalHeader}     redacted 
    ${APP_UUID}             redacted
    ${url}                  www.example.com/v1/rest
    ${PRIVATE_KEY}          redacted

*** Keywords ***
I am setup for API calls to the server
    [Arguments]    ${Excel File Path}  ${Sheet Name}   
    # Get values from Excel
    # log to console      APP_UUID= ${APP_UUID}, private key = ${PRIVATE_KEY}  
    ${auth}   Auth    ${APP_UUID}    ${PRIVATE_KEY}
    

When I call server with 'index'
    ${fullurl}     ${url}/${uuid}/index
    ${headers}    "{'additonalheaders': ${additionalHeader}}"

    ${result}      requests.get(${fullurl}, auth=${auth}, headers=${headers})
```

But I am getting "Imported library 'auth_client.requests_auth' contains no keywords"
And I can't get it to find Auth.

I've tried a few other variations, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Robot isn't really designed for you to just import a random python module and use it. You can, but that's not really how it's designed to work.

Instead, you should create a new keyword library in python that adds an abstraction layer on top of the library you are wanting to use.

For example

```
class MyClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app_uuid = "redacted"
        self.private_key = open("private_key", "r").read()
        self.signature = Auth(APP_UUID, private_key)

        self.uuid="redacted"
        self.url = "https://www.example.com/v1/rest/{}/index".format(uuid)
        self.headers = {'AdditionalHeader': 'redacted'}
    
    def perform_get_request(self, path):
        """Example:  Perform GET request  /index"""

        result = requests.get(f"self.url{path}", auth=self.signature, headers=self.headers)
        return result
```

Then, within a test you would import `Client` as a library so that you can use the keyword.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  MyClient
      
*** Test Cases ***
Example
    ${result}=  perform GET request  /index
    ...
```

Comment: Yep - That's what I am doing now. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You have no class or keyword in your python code. here is a example from the user [guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-name)

```
from example import Connection

class MyLibrary:

    def __init__(self, host, port=80):
        self._conn = Connection(host, int(port))

    def send_message(self, message):
        self._conn.send(message)
```

you need to create library with the same name as the class, in this case ***MyLibrary.py*** and then you can use ***send_message*** keyword in robotframework.

Comment: I wasn't trying to call the python, I was trying to re-write the python in robot language, but after thinking about it overnight, I am starting to think about doing what you suggested.  Write my own class in python and just call the module from within robot.